# Webpack - Move single file in separate blob

Tags: angularjs, webpack, blob, config

I have a config file in my angular app that looks like:

```
angular.module('myMod').value({api: '/api/v1'});
```

The folder structure in my app is:

```
src/
  - index.ts
  - app
    - config
      - config.ts //the file above
    - module1
    - ...
```

Now I'd like to build all my app in a single blob except for the `config` that should be in a separate file.

I tried to add an entry that match that config file:

```
entry: {
  config: `./${conf.path.src('app/config/style.config.ts')}`,
  app: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
  vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
},
```

and a new blob is generated for that file, but the content looks to be:

```
webpackJsonp([1],[],[18]);
```

I guess this is later used from webpack to retrieve the content from a bigger map, but how can I have my configuration there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it suits your requirements, check out webpack copy plugin, and just copy the file over.

Comment: That looks to work, is there any way to inject the copied file in the index.html? Thanks a lot!

Comment: cool!, take a look at webpack-html-plugin, it will make an html file with reference to your bundle

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to copy files form one destination to another (your dist folder), may I recommend Webpack's Copy Plugin:

https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin

You can just copy the file over.